# Excel time formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-365

‪Excel 365, formulas sometimes display as small scientific notation instead of zero . The formula cell is set to “general”. Only with time math  after 3:55 am.

```
A1=start time
B1=end
C1=hrs spent on lunch (.5)

(A1-B1)*24-C1.
```

`A1=3:25 b1=3:55` resolved to `0`.

If I shift to `3:26` & `3:56` I get `-4E-16‬` and no formatting will display `0`

Edit: I know I can change the format to number but my question is more about how excel appears to flub ‘.5-.5=0’

Comment: format it as time and date instead ?

Comment: use `ROUND()`? See [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Set-rounding-precision-E5D707E3-07A8-4DF2-810C-218C531EB06A)

Comment: For " `A1=3:25 b1=3:55` " .. is the expected result (hours) .. 24 ( [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(0325+hrs+today++to+0355+hrs+tomorrow)-(0.5+hrs)) )?

Comment: Yes p._phidiot_ but your link has 3:55 as “tomorrow” where I have both on today. Also doing the problem outside of excel won’t help. I know the math, I just don’t know why excel has a problem with it